# How to run unit test in a multi-module play project written in Java

Tags: java, scala, playframework, sbt

So I have the following project structure with a play project, which is written in Java:

```
conf\
modules\
    first\
        app\
        test\
    second\
        app\
        test\ 
build.sbt
```

in my build.sbt I have the following

```scala
lazy val first= project.in(file("modules/first"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayMinimalJava)

lazy val first= project.in(file("modules/second"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayMinimalJava)

lazy val whole = project.in(file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayMinimalJava)
  .dependsOn(first, second)
```

Now, I would like to run the JUnit tests located in each subproject. When I put them at the root in `test/`, they run if I do `sbt test`. But if move them into the subprojects test directory -at `modules/first/test/` and `modules/second/test/`- they do not run.

What would be missing so my tests can run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use aggregation. Here as quote from [sbt docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html)

> Aggregation means that running a task on the aggregate
>   project will also run it on the aggregated projects.

Try using this

```
lazy val whole = project.in(file("."))
  .aggregate(first, second)
  .enablePlugins(PlayMinimalJava)
  .dependsOn(first, second)
```